# Unique value count of comma separated field (PHP - MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql table that looks like this:

```
id  place   interest
1   place1  a,b,c
2   place2  c,d,e
3   place1  a,e
4   place2  f
5   place2  f
6   place3  g,h
```

I need to get unique "place" and "interest" values sorted as per the count.
So, the output for "place" would be

```
place2(3)
place1(2)
place3(1)
```

So, the output for "interest" would be

```
a(2)
c(2)
e(2)
f(2)
b(1)
d(1)
g(1)
h(1)
```

is there a way to do this in PHP-Mysql?

So, far I have been able to get simple column data

```
SELECT place, 
COUNT( * ) AS num 
FROM testtab 
GROUP BY place 
ORDER BY COUNT( * ) DESC
```

Comment: In the current configuration, I don't think you can do it in one query: you'll have to run a query to get the distinct possible values, and then use these values to count the number of appearances.

Comment: If you could properly normalize this data, this would be easy. The comma-separated format you have here goes against most database design practices because it's difficult and expensive to query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mysql is not able to hold arrays, its better to build a new table like this:

```
interest_id interest_name 
1           a
2           b
```

and another one to keep the relations:

```
pk id   interest_id
1  1    1
2  1    2
```

which this id is the id of the records in your main table.

With having this, you can easily use:

```
select count(*) from THIRD_TABLE where id = YOUR_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

```
$place = array();
$interests = array();
foreach($rows as $row){
    if (!isset($place[$row["place"]])){
       $place[$row["place"]] = 0;
    }
    $place[$row["place"]]++;
    $ints = explode(",", $row["interests"]);
    foreach($ints as $int){
        if (!isset($interests[$int])){
             $interests[$int] = 0;
        }
        $interests[$int]++;
    }
}
```

This will give you the two arrays keyed off of the relevant field with the value being the count. If this is going to be a common action in your application it would make more sense to normalize your data as suggested by AliBZ.

Answer (score 0):

This is for the first result you need

```
SELECT place,COUNT(interest)
FROM `testtab`
GROUP by place
ORDER BY COUNT(interest) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

can do this :

```
$inst_row = '';
foreach($rows as $row){
   $inst_row .= $row['interests'];
}

$inst_values = explode(',', $inst_row);
$inst_count = array_count_values($inst_values);

// $inst_count will return you count as you want ,print_r it and format it accordingly
```

Comment: I would have expected to see you `implode()` with commas before exploding on commas.